# How do I link a udpsrc to rtpbin in Gstreamer Rust?

Tags: rust, gstreamer, rtp

I've attempted to create a pipeline for receiving RTP video/audio streams via Gstreamer using the gstreamer-rs crate, but I am not having much luck.  Here is a quick distillation of my approach:

```rust
let udp_src = ElementFactory::make("udpsrc", Some("udp_src"))?;
    udp_src.set_property("port", &5004);
    udp_src.set_property("caps", &"application/x-rtp".to_string());

let rtpbin = ElementFactory::make("rtpbin", Some("rtp_bin"))?;
let pipeline = Pipeline::new(Some("RTP Pipeline"));
    pipeline.add_many(&[&udp_src, &rtpbin]);

udp_src.link(&rtpbin)?;

rtpbin.connect_pad_added(move |src, src_pad| {
        println!("Received new pad {} from {}", src_pad.get_name(), src.get_name());

        let new_pad_caps = src_pad.get_current_caps().expect("Failed to get caps of new pad");
        let new_pad_struct = new_pad_caps.get_structure(0).expect("Failed to get first structure of caps");
        let new_pad_type = new_pad_struct.get_name();

        println!("{}", new_pad_type);
    });
```

But I'm not getting anything from the `connect_pad_added` when I run the code and send UDP signals to the specified port.  I'm not even sure if this is the right approach, and would appreciate any directions on where to find examples or pointers on how to use `rtpbin` with `udpsrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link a udp source to an rtpbin via the following:

```rust
fn get_static_pad(element: &Element, pad_name: &'static str) -> Result<Pad, Error> {
    let pad = element.get_static_pad(pad_name);
    pad.ok_or(Error::msg(format!("Failed to get pad: {}", pad_name)))
}

fn get_request_pad(element: &Element, pad_name: &'static str) -> Result<Pad, Error> {
    match element.get_request_pad(pad_name) {
        Some(pad) => Ok(pad),
        None => {
            let element_name = element.get_name();
            Err(Error::msg(pad_name))
        }
    }
}

let rtp_udp_src = ElementFactory::make("udpsrc", Some("rtp_udp_src"))?;
let caps = Caps::new_simple("application/x-rtp", &[("clock-rate", &90000i32)]);
    rtp_udp_src.set_property("port", &5006);
    rtp_udp_src.set_property("caps", &caps);

let rtpbin = ElementFactory::make("rtpbin", Some("rtp_bin"))?;

    rtpbin.connect("request-pt-map", false, |values| {
        let pt = values[2].get::<u32>().expect("Invalid argument");
        match pt {
            Some(100) => Some(
                Caps::new_simple(
                    "application/x-rtp",
                    &[
                        ("media", &"video"),
                        ("clock-rate", &90000i32),
                    ],
                )
                    .to_value(),
            ),
            Some(96) => Some(
                Caps::new_simple(
                    "application/x-rtp",
                    &[
                        ("media", &"video"),
                        ("clock-rate", &90000i32),
                        ("encoding-name", &"VP8"),
                    ],
                )
                    .to_value(),
            ),
            _ => None,
        }
    })?;

let rtp_udp_src_pad = get_static_pad(&rtp_udp_src, "src")?;
let rtp_recv_sink_pad = get_request_pad(&rtpbin, "recv_rtp_sink_0")?;
    rtp_udp_src_pad.link(&rtp_recv_sink_pad).expect("Failed to link rtp_udp_src_pad and rtpbin");
```

This will correctly fire off the `connect_pad_added` sequence and let you use it with other elements.

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying to which pad of the `rtpbin` you're linking your `udpsrc`, so it probably selects the wrong one here (maybe the one for a sender-`rtpbin`).

Try with `udp_src.link_pads(Some("src"), &rtpbin, Some("recv_rtp_sink_%u"))` instead. Then you should get a `pad-added` with a `"recv_rtp_src_%u_%u_%u"` name. The first number will be 0, the other two will be payload type and the ssrc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I think this gets me a little further, although I'm not getting the pad added event, though in the detailed logs I get `0:00:00.036781100  4317 0x562b7b81e580 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:912:gst_element_get_static_pad: no such pad 'sink' in element "udpsrc"`

Comment: What's the code you're using now? It sounds like somewhere you're trying to use a pad called `"sink"` from `udpsrc`. Are you maybe calling `udp_src.link_pads(Some("sink"), &rtpbin, Some("recv_rtp_sink_%u"))`? The first pad name should be `"src"`.

Otherwise please provide a full example to reproduce this problem.

Comment: I only changed the line `udp_src.link(&rtpbin)?;` to `udp_src.link_pads(Some("src"), &rtpbin, Some("recv_rtp_sink_%u"))`.  There are also a ton of other logs, but I'm not really sure what to look for, as it seems some of the messages just show up as part of initializing a pipeline?